# How to set up an electrobalance?

Tags: experimental-technology, instrument

My school has the instrumentation for a [Guoy balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouy_balance) magnetic susceptibilty experiment: CENCO electromagnet and Cahn-Ventron RM2 electrobalance and a mounting stand for the balance. Unlike the pictures in the Wiki article showing a double-pan balance, the electrobalance uses an internal load cell with a wire hanging out the bottom of the balance unit.  I would like to get it working but I have no idea how to attach the sample to the electrobalance. There is Nichrome wire, but it is not attached, there is a tiny (1 cm diameter) balance pan and there are sample tubes with samples, again unattached.

How do I attach the sample tubes to the electrobalance unit? Or, does anyone know where to access a manual for an RM2? (I've looked at the usual websites and there is no manual here.)

Comment: What question? Don't see one.

Comment: @Doeser So, now are you going to answer my question here?

Comment: @Doeser Just to let you know, nothing related to a modified question showed up on my Physics dashboard.  I don't have the email option turned on because that's simply too much traffic.